# Extract specific region in the image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I have an image in which I am interested in a specific region in the image.. for example I want to extract region 5-same pixel value everywhere (and background 0). Meaning region 3 and 4 should not be present in the output image(should be 0). Here is the image looks like.

[image]

I can do it with a for loop but since the image is large it takes time.. because I have a 3D stack. Any simpler approach would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want in place of 3 and 4? 0 color, transparency? What is the size of the final image?

Comment: same as the original image.. 3 & 4 should be 0.

Comment: first find the pixel intensity of region 5 (lets say region 5 is between 122 and 132 pixel intensity). Then mask out the remain pixels that are outside that pixel intensity by setting them to 0.

Comment: What kind of image is it and how do you define the regions? Do you have (1) a mask for the region, so you know where it is, or (2) different values in the image color channel, defining the region? A very small example would be helpful.

Comment: I set region 5 to unique pixel value..

Comment: so it is like mask with different regions.

Comment: Do you want to set the values of the other regions to the background value?

Comment: similarly region 3/4 are unique values.

Comment: no I am looking for region 5 & 0 (3 & 4 should be replaced by 0, which is background)

Comment: this question amounts to "how do I threshold". you have enough karma to know [ask] and [mre] and why those rules exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's generate some image we can work on.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

img = np.zeros((250,250), dtype=int)
img += np.arange(-124, 126, 1)**2
img = img.T + np.arange(-124, 126, 1)**2
img += np.arange(1, 251, 1)**2

img = (img/(np.max(img)/4.5)).astype(int)

plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: Example image]

Now we can mask it using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
bg_value = 0 # Background value
want_value = 2 # Value that we are interested in

masked = np.where(img == want_value, img, bg_value)

plt.imshow(masked)
```

[image: Masked image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have images and corresponding masks, you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

N, C, H, W = 11, 3, 32, 64
num_labels = 5

images = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(N, H, W, C))
masks = np.random.randint(1, num_labels + 1, size=(N, H, W))

masks_5 = np.where(masks == 5, 5, 0)

images_region_5 = np.where(masks_5[..., None], images, 0)
```

To visualize the process:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = images[0]
image_5 = images_region_5[0]
mask = masks[0]
mask_5 = masks_5[0]

fig, ((ax_im, ax_masked), (ax_mask, ax_mask_5)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

ax_im.imshow(image)
ax_masked.imshow(image_5)
ax_mask.imshow(mask.astype(int))
ax_mask_5.imshow(mask_5.astype(int), cmap="gray")

ax_im.set_title("Original")
ax_masked.set_title("Masked [5]")
ax_mask.set_title("Mask")
ax_mask_5.set_title("Mask [5]")

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot process]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is as simple as:

```
mask = im == 5
```

which gives you a Boolean mask which is True wherever the image has a pixel with the value 5. You can then multiply that by 255 if you want it white wherever the image is 5, or by 5 if you want it to have the value 5 wherever the original is 5.

Note also that this solution requires ONE byte per pixel because it gives you a Boolean mask, whereas using unadorned `np.where()` will take EIGHT bytes per pixel because it gives you an array of `np.uint64`.

Note also that this is 16 times faster than `np.where()` on my machine:

```
%timeit mask = im == 192
937 ns ± 1.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

versus:

```
%timeit a = np.where(im==192, 192, 0)
15.1 µs ± 8.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

Let's make an example, not with 1 ,2, 3, 4, 5 because they are too dark to see, so let's make squares with brightness 64, 128 and 192:

```
import numpy as np

# Make black image
im = np.zeros((100,300), np.uint8)

im[20:80, 20:80]   =  64  # dark grey square on left
im[20:80, 120:180] = 128  # mid-grey square in centre
im[20:80, 220:280] = 192  # light grey square on right
```

[image]

And then, the code you need to select the right-hand square which has value 192 is this:

```
mask = im == 192
```

[image]